# Immigration/customs during layover in Rome

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, rome, short-connections, fco

I will be traveling from Boston to Venice on Alitalia with a layover in Rome.  Will I have to go thru immigration and/or customs/ security in Rome? Will 1 hour 40 minutes be enough time?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. I would [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/45259/edit) the post to add some standard information; not all of it may be relevant, but it never hurts: is this all booked on a single ticket? Are you checking bags? What airlines will be flying each segment? And what nationality passport will you be traveling on?

Answer (score 3):

1. You will go through security the moment you land (which will be in Terminal 3, if I remember FCO correctly).
2. You are entering the Schengen zone in Rome. That's a passport control.
3. Regarding customs, EU differs from the USA and Canada: you do not need to pick up your baggage if you are on a single ticket. You pick up your baggage at the end (Venice) and go through customs. If you have multiple tickets the situation is murkier: you might or might not be able to get the agent in Boston to check your luggage through (if the two airlines have interline agreements or if it is a single airline). This will be very clearly communicated to you and also you will get baggage slips.

Comment: In my experience, one goes through security only before boarding a flight, never immediately on landing.  Indeed, in most cases, one does not go through security at all before boarding the second and subsequent flights of a multiple-flight trip.

Comment: @phoog depends on airport, right? Schiphol has per gate security for example and Heathrow has per terminal security.

Comment: no, I've been to both Schiphol and Heathrow, and I didn't go through security when I landed in either place.

Comment: @phoog and chx Schiphol works differently depending on the terminal/destination and will be switching to a different model – no per-gate security anymore – over the next couple of years (IIRC).